# View file download data in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm working on a corporate website ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) where I have limited access to the tracking setup and am responsible for creating a dashboard using Lookerstudio. My challenge is with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) in tracking downloads from a subdomain (document.domain.com) that hosts the files.

The main website has download buttons that redirect users to the subdomain, with URLs like this: document.domain.com/download/?_ga=2.123456789. However, I can't find this download data in GA4. I don't have full visibility into how tracking is configured, as my access is limited to viewing the code in the head script part of the website.

I'm not seeking real-time data, but I need to ensure that downloads from the subdomain are being tracked accurately in GA4 for the dashboard I am developing. Given these constraints, how can I set up or view tracking for downloads from the subdomain?

FYI: in Universal Analytics I could find the data through behavior > events > top events > event action > serach for file url

I have enabled the file downloads in Enhanced Measurements, and built a custom report to see this data as according to this: https://www.ruleranalytics.com/blog/analytics/track-downloads-google-analytics/ and many other similar guides. However, as the files are hosted on the subdomain it doesn't work.

I have also followed the same guide on the data from the subdomain, without results.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in download feature requires the download URL to end in a recognised extension. Like .pdf, which your example implies they do not.

You may be able to track the clicks via the outbound click feature. Go to Engagement->Events. Find and select the "click" event in the table. Then find the card for "Link URL". Are your download URLs showing up there?

If so, you could create a custom event that fires when the "Link URL" matches one or all of your download URLs. e.g.

- name = Download Link Clicked
- event_name = click
- link_url contains document.domain.com/download/

Then you should start seeing this new event fire when people click on the downloads.